# Concatenating Saddle Series into one Frame

Tags: scala, saddle

I am working with Scala Saddle [Frames](http://saddle.github.io/saddle/saddle-core/target/scala-2.10/api/index.html#org.saddle.Frame) and [Series](http://saddle.github.io/saddle/saddle-core/target/scala-2.10/api/index.html#org.saddle.Series)

Saddle Series can be converted to Frames and Saddle Frames can be concatenated with concat method like this:

```
val frame3 = frame1.concat(frame2)
```

Since I am new to Scala, I am stuck at trying to convert

```
Map[String, Series[String, Double]
```

to

```
Frame[String, String, Double]
```

where Frame column index is Map keys and columns are Map values.

Could somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may have solved this already. If not, here's a solution that seems to fit:

```
object TheApp extends App {

  import org.saddle.{Frame, Index, Series, Vec}

  val inMap = Map(
    "s1" -> Series(Vec(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0), Index("a", "b", "b", "c")),
    "s2" -> Series(Vec(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), Index("A", "B", "B", "C")),
    "s3" -> Series(Vec(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.8), Index("t", "C", "v", "v"))
  )

  val frame = inMap.foldLeft(Frame.empty[String,String,Double]) { (prevFrame, mapElement) =>
    val (key, series) = mapElement
    val f = Frame(key -> series)
    prevFrame.concat(f)
  }

  println(s"Saddle Test map=$inMap frame=$frame")
}
```

What's going on here is that `foldLeft` takes each map element together with the result of the previous computation and calls the supplied function to compute the next value.

Thanks for making me aware of Saddle, I may find it very useful!

Comment: The body of the function could be just `prevFrame.concat(Frame(mapElement))`, but I'll leave the solution as-is for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is an easy way to concatenate vectors side by side, when the index is common among them:

```
import org.saddle.{Frame, Index, Series, Vec}

val ix = Index("2015-03-19", "2015-03-20", "2015-03-21", "2015-03-22", "2015-03-23")
val s1 = Series( Vec(1.0,        2.0,        3.0, 4.0, 5.0), ix)
val s2 = Series( Vec(Double.NaN, 1.0,        2.0, 3.0, 4.0), ix)
val s3 = Series( Vec(Double.NaN, Double.NaN, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0), ix)

val map = Map( "RSI" -> s1, "ADX" -> s2, "SAR" -> s3)

val frame =
  map
  .foldLeft(Frame.empty[String,String,Double]) {
    case (prevFrame, mapElement) =>
      val (key, series) = mapElement
      val f = Frame(key -> series)
      prevFrame.rconcat(f) }
```

The output is:

```
[5 x 3]
                 RSI    ADX    SAR 
              ------ ------ ------ 
2015-03-19 -> 1.0000     NA     NA 
2015-03-20 -> 2.0000 1.0000     NA 
2015-03-21 -> 3.0000 2.0000 1.0000 
2015-03-22 -> 4.0000 3.0000 2.0000 
2015-03-23 -> 5.0000 4.0000 3.0000
```

Notice that *rconcat* is being used.